# Can i implement Wild card SSL certificate on Two Domains?

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, wildcard

I have Wild Card SSL Certificate and i need to implement it on multiple domains. on first it is being implemented and on second i have to implement. Is it possible that i can implement the same certificate on Two Domains. Domains are hitting the same IP Address, means hosted on same server. But having different Domains first is like: https://erp.abc.com and Second is http://app.abc.com. Both application are differently hosted on IIS.

Please suggest.

Comment: If your wildcard certificate is for `*.abc.com` you will not have issues using it for both `app.abc.com` and `erp.abc.com`.

Comment: @13nilux, it's fixed bro..  thanks.. actually i had never did that. so wanted to confirm. :)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your server does support SNI. If your server does, then you can continue the configuration. See http://www.sherweb.com/blog/host-different-ssls-on-one-ip-with-iis-8-sni/

Comment: Since he's using the same certificate for both domains, why does he need SNI support?